# T-SQL Recursive CTE not completing at last record

Tags: sql, t-sql

T-SQL Recursive CTE not completing at last record

I want to be able to recursively go through the contents of a temp table without using a loop
and perform a set of statements

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#ChannelInfo]

CREATE TABLE [#ChannelInfo](
    [ID]            [bigint] NULL,
    [SerialNumber]  [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [channelid]     [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [#ChannelInfo] ([ID], [SerialNumber],[channelid])
SELECT 1 AS ID, 939029 AS [SerialNumber], 12 as ChannelID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 939029 AS [SerialNumber], 13 as ChannelID
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 939029 AS [SerialNumber], 14 as ChannelID
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, 939029 AS [SerialNumber], 15 as ChannelID


;with cte as 
(
    select * from [#ChannelInfo] 
    union all
    select t.* from cte 
        inner join [#ChannelInfo] t on cte.id = t.id + 1
)
select * from cte a
```

Comment: i then tried the following statement but the recursion does not terminate at ID = 4

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the expected output from this query ?

Comment: Expected output should be as follows:
ID    Serial Number     ChannelID
1 939029            12
2 939029            13
3 939029            14
4 939029            15

Answer (score 0):

We initialize our Recursion by the first record, the we compare current record by previous record +1.

We get first record using `MIN()`

```
;with cte as 
(
    select * from [#ChannelInfo] where ID = (select MIN(ID) FROM [#ChannelInfo])
    union all
    select t.* from cte 
        inner join [#ChannelInfo] t on t.id = cte.id + 1
)
select * from cte a
```